# how to write value of variable into current edit file in vim script

Tags: vim

I get a variable's value in vim's script, and how to write it into the file I'm editing now.

e.g.

```
"=== get date
let TodayDate=system("date")
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use `:put` to put the contents of the variable (or expression) into the current buffer

```
:put =TodayDate
```

The help for `:h :put`

```
                                                        :pu :put
:[line]pu[t] [x]        Put the text [from register x] after [line] (default
                        current line).  This always works linewise, thus
                        this command can be used to put a yanked block as new
                        lines.
                        The cursor is left on the first non-blank in the last
                        new line.
                        The register can also be '=' followed by an optional
                        expression.  The expression continues until the end of
                        the command.  You need to escape the '|' and '"'
                        characters to prevent them from terminating the
                        command.  Example: 
                                :put ='path' . \",/test\"
                        If there is no expression after '=', Vim uses the
                        previous expression.  You can see it with ":dis =".
```

---

For mappings and editing `<C-R>=` is probably better than `:put` since it allows you to use the expression register and output the contents at the cursor location. (Take a look at `:h <C-R>`)

Comment: very great! I had read Learn vi & vim editor but didn't found this! thank you! It works well.

Comment: @FDinoff I must've fat-fingered the downvote when voting. I can't change my vote unless you edit your answer. If you edit, I'll change it to upvote. Thanks, by the way!

Comment: Any way of putting the text in the cursor's position?

Comment: To put vim option values to text, you need to add `&` before the option. See an related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604388/how-to-copy-the-value-of-a-vim-option-to-a-register).

Comment: To be clear, if mapping, do you recommend to save variable (TodayDate) to a register, and afterwards to `:put` the register. Is that right?

Answer (score 3):

How about the following?

```
execute "normal! i" . TodayDate
```

This will put you in insert mode and insert the content of TodayDate at the cursor position.

Comment: +1. If textwidth not zero (i.e. inf), then next map save-change and finaly reset it. To not having problems if the string (TodayDate) pass the tw char.
`nnoremap <buffer> <leader>zzz
    \ : let tw_ztc=&tw
    \ <bar> :set tw=0<CR><Esc>
    \ :execute 'normal! o' . str_zzz_01
    \ <bar> :execute 'normal! o' . str_zzz_02<CR>
    \ :set tw=&tw_ztc<CR>
`

Comment: This way is more computer consuming than the accepted, but it holds auto-indentantion.