# How to copy the value of a vim option to a register

Tags: vim

In vim you can set option with `:set`. For example

> :set spell

to enable spell control. And

> :set spellfile=/home/custom_spell.txt

to set the location of the custom spell file.

You can print the value of an option with echo. For example

> echo &spellfile

Now I would like to copy the value of the option spellfile to a buffer. How can I do that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have `:put`

```
:put=&spellfile
```

You have `i_CTRL-R_=`

```
blabla in insertmode ^R=&spellfile^M
```

(with ^R being CTRL-R typed in insert-mode, and ^M the carriage return you'll type to validate the input given to CTRL-R=)

If you want to put it into a register -> `:let @a = &spellfile` (or any other register name -> `:h registers`)